# Changing font size of captions in figures

Tags: fonts, ieeetran

I'm using IEEEtran class for my conference publication in latex. The guideline says that the captions for figures should be in font size 8. I tried all these methods mentioned in this forum but none worked. Can someone guide me on this please. I found out that the problem is with the figures.
The default IEEEtran is somehow being overwritten.
http://rauhut.ins.uni-bonn.de/bare_conf.tex

```
\begin{figure}[tb]
\subfloat[figure A] {
\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{A}
}
\subfloat[figure B] {
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{B}
}
\caption{ this is the caption}
\label{fig:room}
\end{figure}
```

The preamble is

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subfig}
```

Comment: Can you please supply us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: ...since the default seems to be sufficient in terms of the font size already.

Comment: Your MWE doesn't use the IEEEtran document class. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Mico, forgot to add that. I have included the IEEEtran class and am getting this error.

Comment: Thanks for updating your MWE. I get no errors when I write `\input A` instead of `\include{A}`. Do you absolutely need to use the `\include` instruction, or can you make do with `\input`?

Comment: When using the `\include{A}` method, I get no errors (and I get the correct font size, viz., 8pt in the caption) if I write `\caption{Figure caption with fontsize \protect\expandafter\@car\f@size\@nil}` instead of `\caption{Figure caption with fontsize \expandafter\@car\f@size\@nil}` in `A.tex`.

Comment: @Mico,doesn't work in my case even if I change include to input.

Comment: Try `\fontname\font` instead of that strange combination of commands (and remove the now useless `\makeatletter`); I get `ptmr7t at 8.0pt`. The only way I see for not getting an 8pt font is having redefined `\footnotesize`.

Comment: @egreg, This gives me ptmr7t, but doesn't print the font size.

Comment: Then you're using a bogus `IEEEtran.cls` or have redefined `\footnotesize`.

Comment: @egreg, I have downloaded it from IEEE website, so sure of not being a bogus class file. I have neither modified any default font sizes.

Comment: @suzanne: Are you running TeX Live? Then I would suggest running `tlmgr install IEEEtran` and also make sure there is no `IEEEtran.cls` in your working folder.

Comment: @Werner, I'm placing my .cls file in the local folder.

Comment: Finally solved it... usage of \usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} in preamble solved it.. Thanks a ton everyone..

Comment: Er... People don't usually remove MWEs once they've provided them. I've seen plenty of people fail to respond to requests for one but going to the trouble of responding by adding one and then deleting it after the question is answered is a new one on me. Notice that this makes your question rather less useful for other people. That is not, after all, your preamble. If it were, you'd have bigger problems than the wrong fontsize in captions...

Answer (score 3):

With default settings, the class `IEEEtran` already uses font size 8pt for captions:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
  % \maketitle
  \begin{figure}
    \makeatletter
    \caption{Figure caption with fontsize \expandafter\@car\f@size\@nil}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

`\maketitle` or putting the figure into an included file does not change the font size.

```
 *File List*
IEEEtran.cls    2012/12/27 V1.8 by Michael Shell
  ot1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
 ***********
```

Comment: Hi, I get font size of 1 when running this in my tex file even though it is the standard font size of 10. strange !!

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), please. Either you can extend the working example until the problem appears. Or strip the original TeX file down until the problem disappears, then the error is in the code of the latest removal.

Comment: I have main.tex that includes A.tex, B.tex. I guess the problem is that I do not mention \begin{document} and \end{document}. How do I then get this?

Comment: @suzanne: The organization of the TeX source does not matter at all. You can have one file or thousands of files (e.g. one file for each word). As starting point for a MWE you can add the `figure` environment above at that start of the document body, followed by `\clearpage`. If the point size is wrong, replace `\clearpage` by `\end{document}` and forget the remaining part. The you can remove packages and other preamble stuff that do not change the font size of the caption.

Comment: HI, I have edited the question with a MWE.

Comment: @suzanne: The font size does not change in my system. I have added `\listfiles` to get the version of `IEEEtran.cls`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: @suzanne: If you put `\listfiles` at the start of the document, then LaTeX prints a list of versions at the end of the console and the `.log` file.

Comment: @Hieko, this is the output for the version         IEEEtran.cls    2012/11/21 V1.8c by Harald Hanche-Olsen and Anders Christensen

Comment: @Hieko, Using your simple example, I'm able to get the required font, but if I'm using \input to add my files to main.tex, I'm unable to get the required font size.

Comment: @suzanne: It is not really clear, what your MWE is, the question uses `\include`. Make an empty directory, copy the files `main.tex` and `A.tex` there, compile and post the `main.log` for analysis or put the files in this directory somewhere for download.

Comment: I found out that the issue is with IEEEtran being overwritten by subfig.sty somehow as I'm using it for placing my figures in subfloats but unable to fix it.

Comment: @suzanne: `subfig` loads package `caption`. See egreg's [comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170609/changing-font-size-of-captions-in-figures/170610?noredirect=1#comment392896_170630) that package `caption` cannot be used with class `IEEEtran`.

Comment: I've used this   usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} in preamble to avoid overwriting the IEEEtran and solved it. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2):

The problem I had was with the `subfig` package. I removed it and then the figure caption font-size returned to its original size (should be 8pt).

The following are the list of packages that I've noticed so far that causes this unwanted behaviour with the figure caption fonts by default (unless you are able to change them with suitable options):

- `subfig`
- `subcaption`
- `caption`

use the following options for `subfig` to fix it.

```
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
```

Comment: I a not really sure this answers the question. You shouldn't use `subfig` together with `subcaption`, `subcaption` is better. On the other hand, `subcaption` does not work with all documentclasses, since some classes don't want the user to change anything with respect to the layout.

Comment: @Johannes_B: The OP stated that the default 8pt font is being overwritten. Setting  *any* of the above mentioned packages does this operation.