# Change font size of labels in figures to any font size

Tags: floats, fontsize

I want to change the font size of the label of a figure environment to any font size. It's possible to use the package `caption` with the argument `font=Large` for example. But I found no way to choose any font size, e.g. `fontsize=28pt`.

Here an example code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\usepackage[font=Large]{caption}
%\usepackage[fontsize=28pt]{caption} % not implemented


\begin{document}
\parbox[t]{20cm}{

\fontsize{28}{30} \selectfont

\begin{figure}
    %\includegraphics{figure.eps}
    \caption{\label{fig_req_osnr} \fontsize{28}{30} \selectfont My caption.}
\end{figure}

}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: This is not, what I want:
[http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170609/changing-font-size-of-captions-in-figures]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a new value for `font` with `\DeclareCaptionFont`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{xxviii}{\fontsize{28}{32}\selectfont}
\captionsetup{font=xxviii}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{\rule{0pt}{4cm}\rule{4cm}{0pt}}
\caption{My caption}\label{fig_req_osnr}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
\makeatletter
  \l@addto@macro\captionfont{\fontsize{28}{30}\selectfont}
\makeatother
```

to change the fontsize for the whole caption.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\usepackage{caption}
\makeatletter
  \l@addto@macro\captionfont{\fontsize{28}{30}\selectfont}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\parbox[t]{10cm}{
  \begin{figure}
    \centering \fbox{Figure}
    \caption{\label{fig_req_osnr} My caption.}
  \end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```